# AreTransportControlsEnabled not working on visual studio 2012

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, microsoft-metro, mediaelement

I have been trying to integrate built-in controls for media element but the AreTransportControlsEnabled seems to through an error even when I check it on the property panel or add it programmatically on my XAML file.

The error I get is Unknown member 'AreTransportControlsEnabled' on element 'MediaElement'

What could it be?
Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1):

[AreTransportControlsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aretransportcontrolsenabled) is a property new to Windows 8.1. Only solutions that target Windows 8.1 can use this property. Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2013 is the requirement for targeting solutions to this newest version of Windows.